# invalid according to policy policy condition failed starts-with $content-type ""

Tags: policy, fine-uploader

I am trying to upload photo using fineuploader 3.8.2 on Sony Xperia Tipo or HTC Evo 3d with android 4.0 and facing a strange issue. While uploading through camera works, uploading through gallery is not working and giving me 
invalid according to policy policy condition failed starts-with $content-type "" error

```
$('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
        request: {
            endpoint: "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
            accessKey: "MYACCESSKEY"
        },

        signature: {
            endpoint: "myendpoint",
        },

        objectProperties: {
            acl: 'public-read',
            key: =>
                uploaded_image_key = qq.getUniqueId()
                return "#{uploaded_image_key}.png"
        },

        iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: "/myiframe.html"
        },

        text: {
            uploadButton: '<div><i class="icon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload Image</div>'
        },

        uploadSuccess:{
            endpoint: null
        },

        template: 'mytemplate',

        camera: {
            ios: true
        },

        multiple: false,

        retry: {
            showButton: true
        },

        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ["gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"],
            acceptFiles: "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"
        },

        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },

        resume: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }).on('complete', (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) =>
            if responseJSON.success
                $(@el).find('#thumb_pics').append("<img class='thumb' src ='http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/#{uploaded_image_key}.png' title = '#{fileName}' />")
                $('#submit_feedpost').prop('disabled', false)
        ).on('error', (event, id, fileName, errorReason, xhr) =>
            $('#submit_feedpost').prop('disabled', false)
                            alert(errorReason)
        )
```

My policy is like this -

```
'{
"expiration": "myexpirationdate",
"conditions":[
    {"bucket": "mybucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key" , ""],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_status": "200"}, 
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-qqfilename", ""]
    ]
}'
```

My CORS is like this -

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? The device? The JavaScript console?

Comment: You're going to need to provide *some* indication of where the error is thrown and then *any* code that may be relevant to the cause of this error (e.g., client-side js and console messages and maybe even network tab).

Comment: The same error happens on Nexus with android 4.2 when trying to upload photo from gallery but it works fine when directly uploaded from camera

Comment: I gets this error on the UI where default error is displayed by fineuploader just beside the upload button

Comment: Your policy document seems very strange. And are you using Javascript or Coffeescript or are you trying to mix and match (which is not possible). I am not getting any errors using [our S3 demo on the homepage](http://fineuploader.com/#s3-demo) on the Android 4.x stock browser on a Samsung Galaxy tablet.

Comment: Whats wrong with policy document? We are using Coffeescript completely. It works on Samsung Galaxy Tablet...As I mentioned, it doesn't work on Nexus 4.2, HTC one 4.3, Sony xperia 4.0.4 when uploaded from Gallery but works fine when uploaded from Camera

Comment: All the keys that are Arrays are incorrect.

`["starts-with", "$key" , ""],` should be `{ "key": "...." }` and so on....

Comment: Check this out http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html The point is if it works on some android phones then it should work on all but this is not the case. It doesn't work on Nexus 4.2, HTC one 4.3, Sony xperia 4.0.4 when uploaded from gallery but works fine when uploaded directly from camera

Comment: Maybe it's a device issue, then. Does the S3 demo on FineUploader.com work on these devices? If it does not, then we can fairly safely assume this is a device issue, if it does work, then your setup is somehow to blame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to trouble you. I find out the issue. I was using my own policy to sign it rather than signing the policy sent in the post request to my endpoint by fineuploader library. Anyways thanks a lot

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I had the same problem, so thanks for posting your error as it helped me as well.